# How to explicitly clear cookies using WWW::Scripter module in perl?

Tags: javascript, perl, cookies, lwp

Simple **perl** code is:

```
      use WWW::Scripter;
       
      ...
                 
      my $w = WWW::Scripter->new('agent' => 'myAgent');
      $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');
       
      ...
       
      $w->get($url);
       
      ### WWW::Mechanize automatic cookies = good for now
       
      $w->add_header(Referer => $url);
      $url = $w->document->getElementsByTagName('a')->[0]->href;
      $w->get($url);
       
      ...
       
      ### WWW::Mechanize automatic cookies = NOT good for now
      ### ! need to clear cookie jar here !
       
      ...
       
      $w->add_header(Referer => $url);
      $url = $w->document->getElementsByTagName('a')->[0]->href;
      $w->get($url);
```

One of good feature of `WWW::Mechanize` is **automatic cookies**, which is good at some point, but sometimes cookies need to be cleared. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WWW::Mechanize` method `cookie_jar` returns a `HTTP::Cookies` object. The relevant method is indeed named [`clear`](http://perl.org/HTTP%3a%3aCookies#cookie_jar-clear).

Comment: So it would be `$w->cookie_jar->clear` or `$w->cookie_jar()->clear` then?

Comment: Both are valid, when a function/method takes no arguments, the empty parentheses can be omitted. Pick a [style](http://p3rl.org/style) and apply it consistently. If unsure, consult style guides, other people's code and books, e.g. [PBP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735).

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ATTRIBUTES), can't you just reset the cookie jar attribute?

e.g.

```
$w->cookie_jar({});
```

Comment: I am not sure, but wouldn't your code disable cookies at all? I was thinking more about `$w->cookie_jar->clear` or `$w->cookie_jar()->clear` ..?

Comment: If you look at the source, https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#L692, it looks like an empty hash as the argument sets up a new cookie_jar.